# Procedures to launch a fully-operational site on a VPS

Tags: web, hosting, vps

OK, there is a newbie on VPS here.

I want to know what should i need to do in order to launch a site on VPS!(All things in order)
There is a site called [vpsbible](http://www.vpsbible.com) i just don't want to watch all those videos!
I can arrange to do any thing, but i need to know the steps i need take.

What i am asking is `what is the sequence for launching a website on a VPS`!?
i.e from buying a host to DNS configuration, etc...

---

PS: i googled the topic but i didn't find anything solid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy adding a site on VPS server using the VPS hosting control panel - Plesk in Windows VPS, and cPanel in Linux VPS.

1. Login in your hosting control panel.
2. Add a new account
3. Add a new site
4. Create email and FTP accounts
5. Point your domain name to your VPS server via DNS settings.
6. Deploy your site via FTP.

That's it with few steps. :)